# Where do the positive charges come from in P-Type silicon?

Tags: semiconductors

Can you please help me understand P-Type silicon?  I would like to propose a scenario and then ask you a few questions about it.  Scenario: If I take a block of pure silicon and dope it with boron, I now have P-Type silicon.  In this block the silicon atoms all have the same number of electrons and protons, so the silicon atoms are electrically neutral.  There are no silicon ions.  In this block the boron atoms all have the same number of electrons and protons, so the boron atoms are electrically neutral.  There are no boron ions.  The whole block of doped silicon is electrically neutral since the aggregate numbers of electrons and protons are the same.  Suddenly positive charges appear in this block of P-Type silicon.  These positive charges are strong enough to attract free electrons if the block is joined to N-Type silicon.
Questions: (1) If the positive charges in a silicon lattice are created by protons, where did these additional positive charges come from, since no additional protons have been added to this block of P-Type silicon?  (2) Is this phenomenon of positive charges seemingly appearing from nowhere been observed in other chemical or electrical experiments?  Or are P-Type semiconductors the only scenario where this phenomenon occurs?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The key point you're missing is one you've noticed: P-type silicon *is* electrically neutral. The thing about p-type silicon is that it has fewer electrons (more holes) than pure silicon. But, each of those missing electrons is also balanced by one trivalent boron atom replacing a tetravalent silicon atom, so it's still electrically neutral.

Comment: You state that p-type silicon "has fewer electrons (more holes) than pure silicon."  You are not answering my question.  If p-type silicon has fewer electrons than pure silicon, where did the electrons go?  Are you saying that doping with boron actually removes electrons from the silicon?  And if p-type silicon has more holes than pure silicon, where did the holes come from?  Ultimately a hole seems to be nothing more than a portable positive charge.  Where did these positive charges come from?  (That is my original question.)  Are you saying that doping with boron adds protons to the silicon?

Comment: There are fewer electrons and fewer protons both. The point is that there's a "hole" in the valence band as a result of trivalent boron substituting for tetravalent silicon. The hole is, in a way, simply the boron atom's empty orbital. Electrons from other atoms can fill that orbital, but that leads to another atom (of silicon or boron) having an empty orbital; this is a hole moving from one atom to another.

Comment: The electrons didn't go anywhere, they just got diluted. Just like if you take a pile of salt and mix sugar into it, the sodium and chloride ions didn't go anywhere, they're still there, they're just slightly more dilute.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question: how can two different kinds of neutral atoms bond into a tetrahedral crystal structure and somehow create locations of positive charge that apparently is equal to the charge of a proton? First: positive charge only comes from protons. No combination of electrons can produce a positive charge. So, obviously the nucleus of the Boron atom is being pulled towards the non-bonded electron on the adjacent silicon atom. Boron's three valence electrons bond covalently to three adjacent silicon atoms, this holds the Boron atom in place in the structure. At that point, we have a nonbonded silicon electron and a non-shielded Boron nucleus in the same local area. This obviously stretches the Boron atom so that the positive nucleus charge is "exposed" which creates the so-called positive "hole". So, when a free electron enters this Boron and non-bonded electron location, the free electron will get pulled towards the stretched Boron atom. Stretched atoms are common in chemistry and they create ionic molecular regions.

Answer (score 0):

> In this block ... [t]here are no silicon ions. In this block the boron atoms all have the same number of electrons and protons, so the boron atoms are electrically neutral. There are no boron ions.

That is not correct. In a block of boron doped silicon, most of the boron atoms are negatively ionized, and there are an equal number of silicon atoms that are positively ionized.

Boron is an "acceptor" type of dopant in silicon. When isolated boron atoms are in a crystal that expects each atom to bond to 4 neighbors, the boron atom accepts an electron from one of its neighboring silicon atoms. The boron atom becomes negatively charged, and the silicon atom becomes positively charged. This is the thermodynamically preferred state at normal electronics operating temperatures.

The energy required to remove electron from a silicon atom in the crystal is nearly exactly the same as the energy released by an electron rebonding to a positively charged silicon ion. Thus, an electron can relatively freely move from the neutral silicon atom to the silicon positively charged silicon ion. The two silicon atoms exchange roles. The neutral atom becomes a positive ion, and simultaneously, the positive ion becomes a neutral atom. We call the positive silicon atom a "hole", and refer to the process described as a movement of holes.

The analogous process with boron atoms only takes place rarely, because the boron atoms are so far apart, and because most of the boron atoms are already ionized. That is, a negatively charged boron ion rarely gives up an electron to a neutral boron atom. Thus, the charges attached to the boron atoms are more or less stationary. Generally we treat that process as negligible.

> These positive charges are strong enough to attract free electrons if the block is joined to N-Type silicon.

Since the number of positive silicon ions in block of boron-doped silicon is matched by an equal number of negative boron ions, they don't create an electric field, and they don't attract free electrons.

What *does* happen is that since there fewer *free* electrons in the P-type silicon than in the N-type, when a region of P-type is joined to a region of N-type, free electrons will diffused from the region of higher density to the region of lower density, or in other words from the N-region to the P-region. This diffusion causes the P-region to become negatively charged, and the N-region to become positively charged. These charges *do* create an electric field at the junction of the two regions. A similar process occurs with holes. The holes diffuse from where they are concentrated, i.e. the P-region, to where they are less concentrated, i.e. the N-region. This contributes to the P-region becoming negatively charged, and the N-region becoming positively charged, and thus contributes the electric field at the junction between the P and N regions. The electric field at the junction of the P and N regions causes free electrons to drift back to the N region, and holes to drift back to the P region. In equilibrium, the drift current of electrons in one direction matches the diffusion current in the opposite direction. Likewise for holes.

> If the positive charges in a silicon lattice are created by protons, where did these additional positive charges come from, since no additional protons have been added to this block of P-Type silicon?

I think it is confusing to think of positive charges being *created* by protons. Protons *have* positive charges. Electrons *have* negative charges. The total number of such charges does change in the block of silicon. (We ignore any radioactivity.) The only thing that happens is that the spatial distribution of electrons *does* change. Electrons move to acceptor ions. Electrons move away from donor ions. Electrons move to the side of the junction where they are less concentrated. The protons are bound to nuclei, and those nuclei are bound within the crystal structure, and their migration is negligible (except when we are considering the degradation of a semiconductor device).

> Is this phenomenon of positive charges seemingly appearing from nowhere been observed in other chemical or electrical experiments? Or are P-Type semiconductors the only scenario where this phenomenon occurs?

The description of "positive charges seemingly appearing from nowhere" is rather inaccurate. But the processes of rearrangement of charges occurs in other cases as well, for example batteries. In a battery, charge carrying ions diffuse towards areas of lower concentration. These areas of lower concentration exist because the ions chemically react near these areas, and that chemical reaction consumes those ions and lowers their concentration. I am sure other examples that share some similarities with doped semiconductors can be adduced as well.